# jQuery animate loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a problem with animate loop. There is an object i want to move in a special way and do it in loop. Are there any native options to make it? I have this:

```
$(function () {
    function runIt() {
        $('#div').show("slow");
        $('#div').animate({"marginLeft":"300px"},8000);
        $('#div').animate({"marginLeft":"0px"},8000);
        $('#div').hide("slow", runIt);
    }
    runIt();
});
```

But it seems not so pretty.

Comment: Looks pretty good to me. kingjiv's answer with the indentation makes it look even better.

Comment: kingjiv's solution looks a likely candidate, the only thing I would add to it is consideration of the 'onComplete' function allowed within the animate function. Look at jQuery Api Docs for more info!

Comment: I added a link in my answer to an [old fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/VfAyD/) of mine where I use a small plugin and custom queues. Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is how I would do it.  The only suggestion I would make is to use chaining for nicer code and so the jquery object doesn't get created every time.

```
$(function () {
   function runIt() {
      $('#div').show("slow")
               .animate({"marginLeft":"300px"},8000)
               .animate({"marginLeft":"0px"},8000)
               .hide("slow", runIt);
   }

   runIt();
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but is there any other way to do the same thing more pretty without using callback-hack?

Comment: Craptastic! We had the same idea ;)

Comment: It's not a hack, in my opinion it's the best way to do it.  When the animation is complete you start it again.  The only other way that I can think of is setTimeout or setInterval, but that's much uglier.  You'd have to figure out how long your animation runs and set the timeout to that... ugly.

Comment: thanks, that all i want to know. i thought may be jquery has something special for loop animate, but this option works for me good.

Comment: I believe the semicolons on lines 4 and 5 are accidental.

Comment: @Chris yup, thanks.  Didn't mean to leave them in when I edited the code.

Comment: Won't this eventually cause a stack overflow?

Comment: @AlexFord No it won't.  It's not true recursion.  The call to `runIt` completes.  The next call to `runIt` is called as a callback to `hide` and at that time the first `runIt` is done and off the stack.

Comment: I had two functions recursively calling eachother.  Excellent solution here.

Answer (score 17):

That's the proper way to queue animations. However, there's some things that can be made to your code to make it a bit snappier and prettier:

- Store a reference to the selected element in a local variable to speed up execution (less queries made to the DOM)
- Clean it up by removing unnecessary quotes for object properties
- Sizing is measured in pixels per default so we can use pure integers instead
- The named function can be replaced with a immediately invoked anonymous function and then use `arguments.callee` as the callback

Here's an example showcasing the above changes:

```
$(function () {
    var element = $("#div");
    (function(){
        element
            .show("slow")
            .animate({ marginLeft: 300 }, 1000)
            .animate({ marginLeft: 0 },   1000)
            .hide("slow", arguments.callee);
    }());
});
```

You can also do it in a more advanced way by creating your own plugin to use custom queues. I created a [small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/VfAyD/) a while back when I was fooling around with animation queues.

More about immediately invoked function expression can be read on [Ben "Cowboy" Alman's blog](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

Comment: in a more generic case one may call arguments.callee(); as a separate line