# Animate continuously onmouseover?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, onmouseover

Ok so I looked for a fix on here already and I've tried them all but they use different codes that frankly are too complicated/different for me to understand. I have this animate code working, but you need to re-hover for the animation for it to continue or it stops. Basically I want it to continue animating until I stop hovering over the left and right arrows.

Jquery:

```
<script language="javascript">
function games_animate(px) {
$('#games').animate({'marginLeft' : px} );
}
</script>
```

Html:

```
<input type="image" src="images/leftslide.png" onmouseover="games_animate('+=150px')"  />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
<input type="image" src="images/rightslide.png" onmouseover="games_animate('-=150px')" />
```

Anything I can add to the exsisting code to make this work?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: I need more help that that. I'm not a coder, it took me a long while to get the code you see above working as its so simple. I need someone to just explain how to add a loop into this code so it continuously moves when I am hovering over the button. I am not looking to completely re-code anything unless someone can literally paste it in the way I have so I can pop it in the document.

Comment: This answer on "animate loop" will answer to your question most probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344544/jquery-animate-loop

Comment: Honestly, I just don't understand any of this. The main problem is I'm not a JQ coder, so I can't work out what is vital string of code and what is a custom name of an object or div. I'm so confused... Everything is always so vague on here.