# How to loop this jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, animation

I created this jQuery script following a thousand tutorial and only got this far, how can i loop it since it freezes when it reaches the last slide

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slide').hide();
    $('.slide-1').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('.slide-2').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('.slide-3').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $('.slide-4').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344544/jquery-animate-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Put your animation in a function and when you reach the last step, call the function again from within its own body. It's called recursion.

```
function animate()
{
   $('.slide').hide();
    $('.slide-1').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        $('.slide-2').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('.slide-3').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $('.slide-4').fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow',animate);

            });
        });
    }); 
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    animate();
});
```

NB: you might want to fine tune what happens where.

Comment: the call to animate again should be as a parameter to the last `fadeOut` otherwise it'll run concurrently instead of after that animation has finished

Comment: I always get tripped up with JS's async characteristics.

Comment: No, you want just `animate` (no parentheses) otherwise you're passing the *result* as the callback instead of a pointer to the function

Answer (score 0):

It may be locking up your render thread so try this: 
setTimeout will execute the work without locking up the ui and this is recursive - working for slide-1 to slide-4 then starting at 1 again

```
var slides = [".slide-1",".slide-2",".slide-3",".slide-4"];

function slide(id){
    $(slides[id]).fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function(){
        slide(id%slides.length);
    });
}

$(function(){
    $('.slide').hide();
    setTimeout(function() {
        slide(1);
    }, 0);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, had a few edits as I didn't understand you first time. This should do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be simplified by holding an array of your slides and only having the `fadeIn`/`fadeOut` code once:

```js
$('.slide').hide();
var slides = [".slide-1",".slide-2",".slide-3",".slide-4"];

(function next(i){
     var slide = slides[i%slides.length];
    $(slide).fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow',function(){
        next(i+1);
    });
})(0)
```

```css
.slide{
    width:100px;
    height:100px
}

.slide-1{
 background-color:red
}
.slide-2{
 background-color:blue
}
.slide-3{
 background-color:green
}
.slide-4{
 background-color:yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide-1 slide"></div>
<div class="slide-2 slide"></div>
<div class="slide-3 slide"></div>
<div class="slide-4 slide"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

USE next() in simplest way loop animaton

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slide').hide();
    animate($(".slide-1"));
});

function animate(curr) {
    curr.fadeIn('slow').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        animate((curr.next().length) ? curr.next() : $(".slide-1"));
    });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3pnxx9h3/6/)**

Comment: Try with a `<br>` , or other element within `html` , between a `.slide-*` element http://jsfiddle.net/3pnxx9h3/8/

Comment: @guest271314 . i already implemented  ...did u check in my revision  or http://jsfiddle.net/3pnxx9h3/5/ ,, but OP did not tel  as u expected